# How to loop and .apply a lambda function on a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, apply

I'm building a ML model. I would like to run the prediction bit a few times and then calculate the mean of the accuracy scores.

My code looks like this:

```
predictions = test_df[['histor', 'philosoph', 'cook', 'roman', 'bibl']].apply(lambda x: baseline.predict(*x), axis=1)

y_true = test_df["label"].values

print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_true, predictions))
```

Is there a way to loop the predictions? The desired results would be: let's say n=10. Predictions are run 10 times, I get all the accuracies printed for each run and also the mean of all of them at the end.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It is exactly what [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score) does. Check this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the accuracy scores in a list, and then use that list to calculate the mean accuracy at the end

```
import numpy as np
 n = 10
accuracies = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    predictions = test_df[['histor', 'philosoph', 'cook', 'roman', 'bibl']].apply(lambda x: baseline.predict(*x), axis=1)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, predictions)
    accuracies[i] = accuracy
    print("Run ", i+1, " Accuracy: ", accuracy)

mean_accuracy = np.mean(accuracies)
print("Mean Accuracy: ", mean_accuracy)
```

or

```
n = 10
accuracies = []
for i in range(n):
    predictions = test_df[['histor', 'philosoph', 'cook', 'roman', 'bibl']].apply(lambda x: baseline.predict(*x), axis=1)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, predictions)
    accuracies.append(accuracy)
    print("Run ", i+1, " Accuracy: ", accuracy)

mean_accuracy = sum(accuracies) / n
print("Mean Accuracy: ", mean_accuracy)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use sklearns cross_val_score for this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
X = test_df[['histor', 'philosoph', 'cook', 'roman', 'bibl']]
y = test_df["label"].values
cross_val_score(baseline, X, y, cv=10)
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't use this for my baseline as it was self-made, but i ended up using it to compare the different models i used later on